# Invoke-VMScript - variable into parameter "-scripttext"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to modify IPs of VMs by using Powercli from my computer.

I'd like to use the Invoke-VMScript but I can't find a way to import the result of $vms.ip and vms.gateway (one of the header) into the parameter "-scripttext".

The VM can't find the variable since it does not know it.

```
$vm= import-csv C:\temp\create_vm.csv -Delimiter ';'

foreach($vms in $vm){

Invoke-VMScript -VM $vms.machine -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText 'New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -ipaddress $vms.ip -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $vms.gateway' -GuestUser test -GuestPassword test
```

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes mean PowerShell will not expand the variables - it will use the literal string $vms.gateway.

```
$vms = @{
    gateway = "test"
}

$vms.gateway      # prints test

"$vms.gateway"    # prints System.Collections.Hashtable.gateway
"$($vms.gateway)" # prints test

'$vms.gateway'    # prints $vms.gateway
'$($vms.gateway)' # prints $($vms.gateway)
```

You will need to use [subexpressions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions/) to access the properties of the `$vms` variable, and to escape the double quotes around `Ethernet`, or use single quotes for that part:

```
$script = "New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet' -ipaddress $($vms.ip) -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $($vms.gateway)"
-ScriptText $script
```

<sub>Updated to assign variable as per [Example 3](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html)</sub>

Comment: But the command "Invoke-VMScript" means that it will start the script within the VM itself (using parameter -scripttest). In this case, the VM does not know the variable at all since the CSV file is on my computer.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to add the IP itself instead of the $vms.ip " into -scripttext" ? (thank you for your great answer :) )